# angular2 using router.subscribe to watch url change

Tags: angular, router

I'm using `router.event.subscribe` `@angular/router` to watch the url change to execute an `if` statement though `event.subscribe` works fine. But my question is how can I avoid repeating my `if` statement just to show the title on these urls. It's probably something else than `router.subscribe` but not sure what to use for this.

basically wanted a dynamic title based on the url you are on.

```
this._router.events.subscribe((event) => {
            console.log('route changed');
            if(this.location.path() == '/1'){
                this.title = 'Title 1';
            } else if(this.location.path() == '/2'){
                this.title = 'Title 2';
            }
        });
```

I don't know if that make sense at all. I could change my route.ts paths to have something like `{ path: 'Title-1' }`and just remove the `-` by doing `.replace()` but doing this will give me www.mysite.com/Title-1 but it doesn't look very friendly.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my approach which works fine, especially for nested routes:

I use a recursive helper method to grab the deepest available title after a route has changed:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  title: string;

  private getDeepestTitle(routeSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    var title = routeSnapshot.data ? routeSnapshot.data['title'] : '';
    if (routeSnapshot.firstChild) {
      title = this.getDeepestTitle(routeSnapshot.firstChild) || title;
    }
    return title;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.title = this.getDeepestTitle(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This is assuming, that you have assigned page titles within the data property of your routes, like this:

```
{
  path: 'example',
  component: ExampleComponent,
  data: {
    title: 'Some Page'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** You can use camel case. See it used at end part of answer

```
this.title = camelize(lastPartOfUrl.replace(/-/g,' '));

function camelize(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w|\s+)/g, function(match, index) {
    if (+match === 0) return ""; // or if (/\s+/.test(match)) for white spaces
    return index == 0 ? match.toLowerCase() : match.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

Answer is the using some logic/trick.

Proof with simple javascript (a must working solution)

```
 this._router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        console.log('route changed');
        var url = window.location.toString();
        var ar = url.split('/');
        var lastPartOfUrl = ar[ar.length-1];
        this.title = "Title "+lastPartOfUrl ; 
    });
```

With angular path (only if you don't like the above simple way).. Now same logic but only if `.path()` is working correctly for you

```
 this._router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        console.log('route changed');
        var lastPartOfUrl = this.location.path();
        this.title = "Title "+lastPartOfUrl ;            
    });
```

**Edit**

Above will give you `Title 1`. And if you really want dynamic titles then you must have to follow some pattern off course. Either you have to use `if` or you have to use some formula/pattern

Say your current url is
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613960/angular2-using-router-subscribe-to-watch-url-change` . You can get the best of title from that url could be like

```
 this._router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        console.log('route changed');
        var lastPartOfUrl = this.location.path();
        //this.title = lastPartOfUrl.replace(/-/g,' '); //following will be the result
        //angular2 using router subscribe to watch url change 
        this.title = camelize(lastPartOfUrl.replace(/-/g,' '));
//Angular2 Using Router Subscribe To Watch Url Change 


    });
```

Comment: I had this approach in my head as well but by doing this I will have something like title-1 or dashboard-3. Substring or regex this will be a pain as urls have different character counts. Was hoping to have "Title 1" as the end result, I guess that's why I did the if statement.

Comment: Sorry can not get you clearly. It wont give you `title-1`, but it is giving `Title 1`. subscribe-to-watch-url-change. Please see my edit at ending of answer

Comment: Thanks, no it won't give Title 1 but it now it will give me title 1. Isn't there a way to have like (Dashboard Preview Test) than (dashboard preview test). Well unless I make the path: 'Dashboard-Preview-Test' in my route.ts but that will give me www.mysite.com/Dashboard-Preview-Test in the url.

Comment: Of course there is and its simple use camel case. And i said it will give title when typed hardcocded "Title ", using regex yes it will give "title".

Comment: Now see plz edited answer. It will give you camelized title.