# Router.url always return slash and not current url

Tags: angular

I don't understand why in this case, my current url return '/' when i refresh my page on '/component'

Why it not returns '/component' ?

But on this.router array, url is right...

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4jlux

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((routerData) => {
      if(routerData instanceof ResolveEnd){ 
         if(routerData.url === 'your url'){
           //Do something
         }
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the app-component is the container for router-outlet, so it's init cycle will happen before the router functionality. If you log the `router.url` from the child component, it should be what you expect.

Comment: Thanks it works, but is it possible to have the right url from parent component?

Because if I have N childs, i can't call router.url from all childs

Comment: Can you add that log to the afterContentInit lifecycle method https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit and see if that gives you what you want? Alternatively you can subscribe to router events. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40468374/10747134